# PHP str_replace special chars

Tags: php, str-replace

im trying to replace two ?? chars inside an HTML file as follows:

```
<?php
$file="test.html";

$q1 = "??";
$q2="?";

$string=file_get_contents($file);

$string=substr_replace("$q1", "$q2",$string);
file_put_contents($file, $string);
?>
```

but im afraid its not working. it works fine with normal text.

any ideas? thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working?

Comment: its not replacing the two ?? simbols , it should change to just one ?

Comment: [`substr_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) **is not** [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). You call `substr_replace()` but you pass it the arguments expected by `str_replace()`. Of course it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the parameter set for a `str_replace()` but in a `substr_replace()` call.

Try

```
$string=str_replace($q1, $q2,$string);
```

> [The manual substr_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php)
>
> [The manual str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php)

Can I suggest that you add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) *while testing* right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: thanks for your help but still not working

<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$file="test.html";

$q1 = "??";
$q2="?";

$string=file_get_contents($file);
$string=str_replace($q1, $q2,$string);
file_put_contents($file, $string);
?>

Answer (score 0):

finally i found a solution, it works like this:

```
$q1 = "??";
$q2="?";

$cadena=utf8_encode(file_get_contents($nombrearchivo));
$cadena = html_entity_decode($cadena, ENT_QUOTES);
$cadena=str_replace("$q1", "$q2",utf8_encode($cadena));
file_put_contents($nombrearchivo, $cadena);
```

Comment: You might have mentioned in your question that you were using a UTF-8 encoded data in the input file!